# question about my pixels resolution for my poster

Tags: pixel, pixelation

I have a question about pixels.
I made a background for a poster for a party.
Put i think when i make the picture larger you will see a lot of pixels.
Can someone help me to fix this?
If you can help me it would be wonderful!

[image: my poster]

I made this in photoshop cs6.

thx jenten

Comment: What resolution do you have? ALL bitmaps will give the lego-effect if you zoom in too much.

Comment: We need a lot more information, namely: what is the resolution of your current image, and what dimensions are you planning on printing your poster as.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to consider when preparing a poster for print. They are briefly mentioned in some tips [here](http://www.nuigalway.ie/remedi/poster/print.html)

There is a more in depth guide to poster printing [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/print-design/how-to-print-a-poster-12121447)

And a good step by step guide [here](http://www.printaholic.com/how-to-make-a-poster-in-photoshop/)

To briefly cover it though. You need to make sure that your image size and resolution are appropriate for the poster that you make. You don't want to have to make the picture larger after you've designed it. It's better to make it larger from the beginning.
You can check your current image size by going to Image > Image Size in Photoshop or by hitting CTRL+AlT+I

If the image size here is not the size that you want to print  then it would be best to open a new file with the appropriate size preferences. (File > New or CTRL + N) In these preferences you want to ensure that the width and  height are set as you need them (which could be a little larger than the final poster size if you want to accommodate for a [bleed](https://www.rubiks.ca/resource-center/useful-printing-tips.html?lang=EN) and [crop marks](http://desktoppub.about.com/od/glossary/g/Crop_Marks.htm)) You also want to make sure that the Resolution is set to at least 300dpi to ensure that your image doesn't become pixelated.

When printing it's also better to set your colour mode to [CMYK](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/C/CMYK.html) instead of [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) which would be more appropriate for web.

There are lots of print resolution questions [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=print%20resolution) that you might like to consider reading over to help with your current issue.

Also **don't** just change your resolution on the image size of the poster that you have. If you are increasing this (i.e 72 dpi to 300dpi) then your image will become significantly smaller to preserve quality and you'll just run into many more issues.

If you need to significantly increase the size of your file you are better off in terms of quality to just remake it using your current layers for reference in the new file.

I hope my advice and links help you out. Glad to see you managed to recreate the background that you were having issues with. :)

Good luck!